# 429-THROTTLED error code AMQPS over WS for Azure IoThub

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I have S1 instance of IoT hub with 1 IoT hub unit, I have tried sending 10000 messages without any delay simultaneously. I was expecting to receive error code 429-THROTTLED, but I'm not getting any error code back, messages are getting to IoT hub slowly(it took 2hours once, it took 1minutes once without consistency). I'm using java SDK, I have tried it with 1.5.37 and also with 1.10.0

What should I do to get 429-THROTTLED error code?

Comment: I get MESSAGE_EXPIRED when testing [send-event sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/tree/fa73d09b6c34007cbee911c4e2a9b1ca8b42e0b4/device/iot-device-samples/send-event). If you do not use the sample, have you implemented [event callback](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/fa73d09b6c34007cbee911c4e2a9b1ca8b42e0b4/device/iot-device-samples/send-event/src/main/java/samples/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/SendEvent.java#L21) to check IoT Hub status code? Can you see how many messages arrived in Azure Portal per minute?

Comment: I have my own implementation which is similar to send-event and I do have event callback implemented. I do get MESSAGE_EXPIRED if I have message_Expiry time set on the message. If I do not have message expiry set, it takes time to send out all the messages without throttling

Comment: If I don't set message timeout, I can send about 4000 messages successfully(I use device explorer to receive) and then I get [MESSAGE_CANCELLED_ONCLOSE](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/fa73d09b6c34007cbee911c4e2a9b1ca8b42e0b4/device/iot-device-client/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/device/IotHubStatusCode.java#L26) status code.

Comment: (continue)And it sends about 200 message per second. It should be throttled based on [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling). but I don't get [THROTTLED](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/fa73d09b6c34007cbee911c4e2a9b1ca8b42e0b4/device/iot-device-client/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/device/IotHubStatusCode.java#L21) status code. I'll report this issue internally and update here ASAP.

Comment: thank you, please let me know if you create a defect, so that I can follow the defect for updates.

Comment: The issue is reported and waiting for the response. BTW, can you share why you need get the THROTTLED error?